# Setting notifications based on timepicker and Spinner value

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I have two time picker and spinner with value 1 to 10, I want to make number of local notification selected from spinner  between time selected from two time picker for eg from 2 pm to 6 pm I want to show six notification and it should notify every day between selected time range with selected value, I have used alarm manager for this but it showing just one notification also used set repeating.

Also I tried to first find time difference from two picker in millis and applied some logic but nothing seems to be good. Please give me some logic or sample code will be appreciated.

Some code snippet is

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
    myIntent, 0);
long next = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < spinnervalue ); i++) {
    Log.e("checkkkk ", "" + "checkkkk");
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  next, pendingIntent);
    next += diff_millis;
}
```

Comment: Can you post any of your existing code?

Comment: Please check this ... diff_milis is the time difference  from two time picker ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet should work, perhaps with a few changes.
Here i am getting the difference between the 2 time pickers in milliseconds and += to the current time in milliseconds. Giving each pending intent a different ID and telling it to update and existing one if available (allows you to reset them if you know the ID (counter).
You have to divide the difference by the spinner chosen in order to get evenly spaced millisecond differences.

```
//Assume timepicker2 > timepicker1
int hours1 = timePicker1.getCurrentHour();
int minutes1 = timePicker1.getCurrentMinute();
int hours2 = timePicker2.getCurrentHour();
int minutes2 = timePicker2.getCurrentMinute();

int hourDiff = hours2-hours1;
int minutesDiff = minutes2-minutes1
int millisecondsDiff = hourDiff*60*60*1000;
millisecondsDiff += minutesDiff*60*1000;
Double period_diff = millisecondsDiff/spinnerValue;

//This is for the intent difference
int counter = 0;
long next = System.currentTimeMillis() + period_diff;

for (int i = 0; i < spinnervalue ); i++) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, counter++, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Log.e("checkkkk ", "" + "checkkkk");
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  next, pendingIntent);
    next += period_diff;
}
```

Don't take the snippet to work definitively as it's a quick jot down, but it should give you a general idea of where you should be looking.

Another idea would be to use `i` as the counter so you know in what range the IDs are.

Comment: i think your code will work let me try it :) thanks assuming if i can find correct time from timepickers

Comment: You can do something like `if((hourDiff*60) + minuteDiff <= 0) {Toast.makeText(this, "Nope, try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); return false;} `

Comment: Thanks jeffrom its working but if in case timepicker1 is  greater than timepicker2 then it willl give negative value so any thing to do in that case ??

Comment: If you use my previous comment, does that work? It's just adding up the difference in seconds and checking it isn't below or equal to 0

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29

> If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered
>   immediately. If there is already an alarm for this Intent scheduled
>   (with the equality of two intents being defined by
>   filterEquals(Intent)), then it will be removed and replaced by this
>   one.

So setting this in a loop isn't what you want.

Your value for millis needs to be a time.  0 would indicate epoch (January 1st, 1970).  What you probably want is "SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + someValue" passed in for that parameter.

Comment: ok so you are saying in place of next = 0 , i should use next = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + someValue"  , okk i will try it and am i using  the right logic ? like getting time differnce using it , how to set numbers for notifications ?